# Right way to redirect after form submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit

Maybe its a stupid question, but what is right way to redirect user to the success page after form is saved in database?

I dont know why, but if I add `action="done.php"`, than the form does not save data to my database.

I tried to add `header ("location:/done.php");` it worked, but when I moved page to original server ( PHP 4 and MySQL 3.23.5 ) there is error when I am trying to send the form `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ........`

Here is my php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$sql="INSERT INTO tekstile_users (id, name, email, company, adress, post, phone)
VALUES
('', '$name','$email','$company', '$adress', '$post', '$phone')";

if (mysql_query($sql,$con)) {

    header ("location:/done.php"); 
    }
    else {
echo "Something is wrong";
}

}//end of submit button
```

I **fix** it converting that .php file to `UTF-8 without BOM` .

Thanks all for suggestions!

Comment: It isnt injection fault, because if I remove -header ("location:/done.php"); everything is alright

Comment: I didn't mean that this issue is caused by SQL injection. I just mean you have a huge security flaw in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **fix** it converting that .php file to `UTF-8 without BOM` .

Thanks all for suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

The "headers already sent" message means that your script has already output something. Is there anything displayed on the web page above this error message? Check for any whitespace before the `<?php` tag. Also check any include files for whitespace before or after `<?php ?>` tags.

The Location header should have a space after the ":" and should be a absolute URI, similar to the following:

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/done.php");
```

Comment: There cant be whitespace, because it is the same code, that works right on localhost and on my server, but doesn't on clients

I tried your advice for long url for header - didnt work.

Comment: Fixing the header will not fix the "headers already sent" error. You missed the end part of the error message. Do you get "output started at..."? If so that will tell you which line of which script has already output something.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/virtual/site167/fst/var/www/html/tekstile/index.php:1) in /home/virtual/site167/fst/var/www/html/tekstile/index.php on line 27

. And 27 line is - header ("location:/done.php");

Comment: Look very carefully at line 1 of index.php. That has caused PHP to output something.

Answer (score 4):

"Headers already sent" most likely means that there is some content in your .php file before your PHP code. This could be as simple as white space, or maybe your PHP code is embedded in HTML. In either case, make sure *nothing* comes before your PHP code, and you should be fine.

As for the correctness of this method of redirect, I believe it is a generally accepted technique.

Answer (score 2):

others have answered with respect to headers already sent. An alternative is to include or require done.php if the update was successful. Don't forget the exit after the include / require.

```
if (mysql_query($sql,$con)) {

    header ("location:/done.php");
    require_once('done.php');
    exit();
    }
    else {
echo "Something is wrong";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use 
`ob_start();`
at the top of page and just after `<?php`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was breaking my head for the past 2 hrs. your code helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

`headers already sent` means that something has already been sent to the browser.

Is mysql giving an error?

Also, note that [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) was introduced in PHP 4.1 so if you are using a really old version of php, that might be causing an error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake PHP Version is 4.3.11 .

I think it is a php error.

Comment: @iKaspars If it worked on your test machine and it does not work on the original server, my guess would be a mysql problem. Does the information get inserted in the database?

Comment: Yes, information is inserting in the database. 

Is there other ways to redirect after success ?

Comment: If I remove header("Location: done.php"); I get no errors and no redirect, but form is submitting and data is inserting into the database

Comment: @iKaspars Very weird. It´s not good practice, but what happens if you use `@mysql_query` instead of `mysql_query`?

Comment: Same thing - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/virtual/site167/fst/var/www/html/tekstile/index.php:1) in /home/virtual/site167/fst/var/www/html/tekstile/index.php on line 27

Comment: @iKaspars The only thing I can think of, is installing a headers plugin for firefox (or chrome probably) and checking what was sent exactly so that you at least know where to look.